# Cite in body of document, but omit from references (i.e., opposite of \nocite)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I can use `\nocite` to add to the references without citing in the paper. But I would like the opposite. I want to cite in the paper without adding to the references. That is, I would like to use by `.bib` file to generate the correct authors and year citation, but omit the full citation from the references section.

I know that this is bad form, but for a short assignment, this would allow me to mention the references without providing the whole bibliography and meet a page limit.

Edit: I am using BibTeX.

Comment: Why don't you just generate the bibliography at the very end of the document, starting on a new page? That way, you get all the benefits of having a "real" bibliography -- e.g., you can check if the references you're generating are actually the correct ones -- and still have the option of leaving off the last few pages when it comes to distribute the document...

Comment: @Mico -- Brilliant! I wanted to have one reference for the subject paper (I am a PhD student writing paper summaries for a seminar), but I can leave that off. Your solution is much more practical and lets me get full citations later. Thanks! Should I close this question?

Comment: Are you using `biblatex`?

Comment: @Werner -- No, `bibtex`. In the near term I won't have the time/energy to switch, but should I add that to my todo list? Other than this odd request I have been very happy with the `bibtex` feature set.

Comment: If you want to omit all entires, `bibtex` is fine, but if someday you only want to omit some of them, then `biblatex` is the best option because you can define custom filters for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to omit all references, you can use `\nobibliography`.

```
\usepackage{bibentry}
...
\nobibliography{your_bib_filename}
...
```

Comment: Where can I find `bibentry`? I can't find it in the TexLive package manager on a Win 7 install. Thanks!

Comment: Download [`bibentry.ins`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/bibentry.ins) and [`bibentry.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/bibentry.dtx) and then compile `latex bibentry.ins`. This produces `bibentry.sty` that you can then use. As mentioned [here](http://ctan.org/pkg/bibentry) (under **Getting It**), it is not available under MiKTeX nor TeX Live.

Comment: @Werner -- Thanks for two good lessons on thinking outside the box!

Comment: I see that the `\nobibliography` can be used to keep the citation from appearing in the bibliography; but how can one simultaneously get an inline bibliographic entry that would typically appear with `\bibentry`?  That is, with `\nobibliography{}`, the `\bibentry` output is likewise null.  I'm looking for inline text of a bibliographic entry, without a place in the actual bibliography.

Answer (score 4):

A far inferior, yet still viable alternative, would be to construct and compile your document as usual. Then, comment out `\bibliography{<bib-file>}` before the last compilation. This will still read the correct citation details from the auxiliary files at the start of the last compile and therefore *not* complain about undefined references while also *not* setting the actual bibliography. It may work as a quick-fix in terms of your needs.