# Don't show bibliography heading if there aren't any citations

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

We use LaTeX to generate PDF documents dynamically from the web. Sometimes reports have bibliography citations, and sometimes they don't.

At the end of our LaTeX document, we have a bibliography block, where all citations are automatically listed (we use BibTeX). But what we want to avoid is to show the bibliography heading when it is empty (with no bibliography entries).

Our actual solution is to add the bibliography block also dynamically, after searching for citations in the final document text, and ensuring that we have, at least, one citation.

Is there another way to do that with LaTeX? I'm thinking about some bibliography block setting or something like this ...

Comment: may be just remove `\bibliography{bibfile}` when there are no bibliography entries why use it anyway.

Comment: Related ? [Cite in body of document, but omit from references (i.e., opposite of \nocite)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46049/15717)

Comment: This might be easier with `biblatex`, which separates loading the bibliography database from printing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As jon has suggested in a comment, this is yet another reason to use [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex). Compare the output of the following two examples -- note that `\printbibliography` (a `biblatex`-specific command that replaces `\bibliography`) is present in both examples.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: xxx]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also be interested in the following question: [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex)